# `readr::read_csv` : Why does it interpret time of the form %H%M%E9S as character, unlike fread, read.csv

Tags: r, data.table, fread, readr

`readr::read_csv` : Why does it interpret time of the form %H%M%E9S as character by default, unlike `fread`,`read.csv`

- Does it interpret it to be a time series ?
- Other packages treat it as double without precision ?

`fread`, `read_csv` interpret it to be double

**file.csv**

```
time
093000.123456789
```

```
> d = readr::read_csv("file.csv")
Parsed with column specifications
cols(
time = character()
)

> d = fread("file.csv")
> d
1 : 93000.12

# If instead the file contained %Y%m%d%H%M%E9S
> d = readr::read_csv("file.csv")
Parsed with column specifications
cols(
time = col_double()
)
```

Comment: Library nanotime uses it .. But in general you may call it to be nanosecs precision..

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example